# Adding IF condition in value columns based on value other column in datatable

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

I want to add a condition where if the status column is "open" then it will bring up "view", while if the status is "closed" or "cancel" then bring up the "view1" column only. is this possible?

model

```
 function json() {
        $this->datatables->select('id_lowongan_pekerjaan,judul_lowongan_pekerjaan,tanggal_berakhir,status,tgl_buat');
        $this->datatables->from('lowongan_pekerjaan');
        $this->datatables->add_column('view', '<a href="lowongan_pekerjaan/edit_lowongan_pekerjaan/$1"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>  
                                               <a onclick="return confirm(\'Apa anda yakin untuk hapus Data ini?\')" href="lowongan_pekerjaan/delete_lowongan_pekerjaan/$1"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>', 'id_lowongan_pekerjaan');
        $this->datatables->add_column('view1', '', 'id_lowongan_pekerjaan');
        $this->datatables->where('status !="delete"');
        return $this->datatables->generate();
    }
```

view

```
columns: [
     {
    "data": "id_lowongan_pekerjaan",
    "orderable": false
     },
     {"data": "id_lowongan_pekerjaan"},
     {"data": "judul_lowongan_pekerjaan"},
     {"data": "tanggal_berakhir"},
     {"data": "status"},
     {"data": "status", 
              "render": function(data) { 
              if (data === "Open") {
                  return {"data": "view"} 
                }
                else {
                  return {"data": "view1"} 
                }

              } 
     },
     //{"data": "view"}
    ],
```

Comment: Where is "Open" coming from? And no, doing it that way isn't going to work but I assume you figured that out by now ;)

Comment: I'm assuming the db column status?

Comment: yes right from column field status.

Comment: hopefully my modified lib will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignited Datatables doesn't have that kind of per column functionality. You can use my "fork" of it that I personally use that allows external callbacks. Just replace the library with mine: https://pastebin.com/Y2mH72SE

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->model('some_model');
```

Then

```
->add_column('view', array($this->some_model, 'callback_view'), 'id_lowongan_pekerjaan, status');
```

and `echo json_encode($this->datatables->generate());`

**Model:**

```
class Some_model extends CI_Model {
    public function callback_view($id, $status) {
        return $this->load->view('some_view', array('id' => $id, 'status' => $status),  true);
    }
}
```

**some_view.php**

```
<?php if ($status == 'Open'): ?>
<a href="lowongan_pekerjaan/edit_lowongan_pekerjaan/<?php echo $id; ?>"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>  
<a onclick="return confirm(\'Apa anda yakin untuk hapus Data ini?\')" href="lowongan_pekerjaan/delete_lowongan_pekerjaan/<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

*A note on usage*

You can still do inline things like: `$this->datatables->add_column('edit', '<a href="profiles/edit/$1">EDIT</a>', 'id');` however it has to be in the `sprintf` form in my version: `$this->datatables->add_column('edit', '<a href="profiles/edit/%s">EDIT</a>', 'id');`